# Not able to view files created in Azure Notebooks

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-notebooks

I am trying to create a new file using Azure notebooks (notebooks.azure.com) and executing the Jupyter notebooks itself doesn't have any challenges or errors, but the actual file is missing in the path

[image: Jupyter notebook script]

The files list after executing the script is below (I should have seen test.txt file which is missing now)

[image: File structure]

Does anyone has inputs?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this - test.txt is showing up fine for me.

One question: was the notebook that you opened and executed this script from in one of the directories above? If so, then the file created will be in the same directory...

Comment: Thanks @Erik, at least it works for me now. Pretty weird earlier it didn't work few days earlier (but I am very sure the directory was same). May be transient considering product is in preview